# Remove Setup Project does not delete it from file system using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, installation

Using Visual Studio 2008 - I add a Setup project (from Setup and Deployment Template) and its called by default Setup1.
I then decide I don't want this so I right click on the project and select **Remove**.

Later on I decide I want to add a Setup project again but it's default name is called Setup2 and when you look at the project folder you can see the old Setup1 files are still there!

Why has Visual Studio not deleted these from the file system when I selected Remove - and is there a way to make it delete them from the file system as default behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing a project only takes it out of the list of projects that are part of the solution file.

It does not remove it from the drive.

If you want to add a new project with the same name, you will need to either delete the original project yourself or add the new one in a different directory.

VS will not delete them, as you may want the project to be part of a different solution. As far as I know, there is no way to remove projects from the drive as a default.